# How to start a program?

Tags: 13.10

Total newbie, I can download programs, but how do I make the program executable?
Using 13.10

Thank you

John

Comment: Can you give an example of the program you'd like to make executable. Usually it's not necessary, so you might also want to elaborate on the reasoning.

Comment: Have you tried looking for it in the menu? What do you mean by downloading programs? Did you download something or install it? Have you tried double clicking the downloaded file?

Answer (score 3):

To make a program executable right click on it, got to `Properties > Permissions` and click on execute box, such as,

[image]

Not sure if this helps. If what you want is to install a program, then this is not the way.